# Flex CSXSInterface returned data

Tags: apache-flex

My attempt is to create an XML collection of the data returned by the CSXSI instance. From the documentation that I have read 
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7caf.html

it seems that the XML has to be returned in a specific format which I have tried to no avail. Ideally what I would like to do is the code below, except something is obviously wrong. The data from the function is getting sent to Flex, but when I try to put it into a XMLListCollection, I am doing something wrong.

Any ideas on this one?

```
// variable declarations---------------------------------------
    private var templateFolder:XML;
    private var templateFolderList:XMLList;
    [Bindable] private var templateFolderCollection:XMLListCollection;

// event handlers-----------------------------------------------
   private function init(event:FlexEvent):void {
                    var labList:SyncRequestResult=CSXSInterface.instance.evalScript("templateHub");                
//returns <template><lab>Daryl</lab></template>
templateFolder = labList.data;
templateFolderList = templateFolder.lab;
//Create an XMLListColection
templateFolderCollection = new XMLListCollection(templateFolderList);
}
```

Comment: What results are you getting from trying to run this code?what makes you think you are doing something wrong?  Are you getting an error?  IF so, what error?  Is this the third question you've posted on this same topic?

Comment: Also, can you post an example of the XML you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Agree with comments, there's nothing wrong with this code, I took what you have above and pasted it into an existing test flex mobile 4.6 project and it works fine, the problem must be with the function call/return value, I replaced that with a XML string defined inline and this works.

We need errors here (or erroneous behavior), or else it's basically impossible to help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View creationComplete="init(event)"
        title="HomeView"
        xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.XMLListCollection;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            // variable declarations---------------------------------------
            private var templateFolder : XML;
            private var templateFolderList : XMLList;
            [Bindable]
            private var templateFolderCollection : XMLListCollection;



            // event handlers-----------------------------------------------
            private function init(event : FlexEvent) : void
            {
                //var labList:SyncRequestResult=CSXSInterface.instance.evalScript("templateHub");                
                var labListData : XML = <template><lab>Daryl</lab><lab>Shaun</lab></template>;
                templateFolder = labListData;
                templateFolderList = templateFolder.lab;
                //Create an XMLListColection
                templateFolderCollection = new XMLListCollection(templateFolderList);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:List dataProvider="{templateFolderCollection}"/>

</s:View>
```

[image: What I see]

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I wish I had more of an idea what I'm doing with this crap myself. A little background on this. The environment for this development is a panel in Photoshop. I have yet to come up with a solution for debugging in this environment, otherwise I would load you up with errors.

Comment: I have used inline XML and yes, everything works great. Using the CSXSInterface class to call over from javascript, I believe is where the problem lies. According to the documentation as listed above there are limited options for returning XML, but I believe I am treating the XML properly. -- Close to giving up.